# How to pool (average) hazard ratios?

Tags: r, regression, survival, multiple-imputation

Let's say the task did not allow me to use either the MICE package or RMS / HMISC to perform survival analysis on multiply imputed data. I had to impute 5 different data sets and calculate separate hazard ratios in each of these.

I need to pool the hazard ratio from each set to one "average" / "pooled" hazard ratio but how is that done? I've searched the web but can't find no formula or package that would facilitate this.

Now, there are plenty of information on pooling hazard ratios for meta-analyses but recall that my estimates originate from the same data which was used to impute 5 complete data sets.

Comment: Have you seen this?http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140761/survival-analysis-multiply-impute-5-datasets-to-average-one-propensity-score-th

Comment: @AdamRobinsson Please see `summary(pool(fit.Cox))` in this [link](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/data-analysis-after-multiple-imputation.html).

Answer (score 4):

Averaging the coefficients just means that: compute the hazard ratios in each of your dataset, add them and divide by 5 (= the number of imputed datasets).

However, Rubin's rules assume that the sampling distribtution (actually, the posterior distribution) of the estimates is normal. This is more likely to be true for log(hazard ratios) than hazard ratios. Remember that a normal distribution covers all negative and positive numbers, while a hazard ratio cannot be negative. So more often the log-hazard ratios are combined using Rubin's rules and than the combined log-hazard ratio is transformed to hazard ratios.

Comment: Thanks @Maarten Buis. Can you recall any reference with the equation to perform the calculation?

Comment: Any book on missing data includes the Rubin's rules, e.g.: Paul D. Allison (2002) *Missing Data*. Thousand Oaks: Sage. Joseph L. Schafer (1997) *Analysis of Incomplete Multivariate Data*. Boca Raton: Chapman & Hall/CRC. Roderick J.A. Little and Donald B. Rubin (2002) *Statistical Analysis with Missing Data*. second edition. Hoboken: Wiley Interscience.

Comment: Indeed I think it would hold better for the log(hazard ratios), i.e. the regression coefficient from the Cox model. This way, the maximum likelihood estimate follows an asymptotic normal distribution.

Comment: I really appreciate the answers, however the source I found dealt with this issue in terms of pure mathematical equations, which makes it difficulr for me to apply. Did I understand it correctly that the hazard ratio, lower and upper bound is obtained by averaging the log of each one of these? Sounds a bit too simple... No standarderror to consider? 

Comment: http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2288/9/57 was a bit equatious...

Comment: That is incorrect. The point estimate is a simple average. The standard error is more complicated. You can look at the appropriate equations in any of the books I have cited. After that you can turn the point estimate and standard error into a confidence interval in the usual manner.

Comment: Multiple Imputation is not a trivial technique. Implementing a non-trivial technique by hand requires skill. Unfortunately, the article you cited represents pretty much the minimal level of equation reading skills you should possess to implement MI by hand.